# calling invalidateOptionsMenu() causes SearchView to stop working

Tags: java, android, searchview, drawerlayout

I am working with a DrawerLayout and I am using invalidateOptionsMenu() whenever it is opened or closed. The trouble is that after opening and closing the DrawerLayout the SearchView stops working.

Class1:

```
private DrawerLayout DrawerLayout;
private ListView DrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle DrawerToggle;
private CharSequence DrawerTitle;
private CharSequence Title;
.....

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.menu, R.string.app_name, R.string.hello) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(Title);
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(DrawerTitle);
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }
};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(DrawerToggle);
```

SearchView defined Class2:

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
}
```

Neither class defines onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Specifically this is what stops working:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
   adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

Where adapter is the adapter for a ListView and getFilter goes to a baseadapter class which implements filterable.

Comment: Give us a stack trace please

Comment: There isn't anything to look at....

Comment: Stopped working -> crashed -> unexpected exception -> whole lot of stack trace. I'd like to find out where the error occured. Plus post the `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, seems important.

Comment: Ok, the app hasn't crashed and I never actually define the onprepareoptionsmenu. No exceptions nothing.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I do not know how to use @TaylorCourtney solution. I appreciate if you could help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756799/android-studio-invalidateoptionsmenu-causes-the-always-visible-items-to-stop

Comment: I think our situations may be a bit different. I would be careful about overriding the onprepareoptions function

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by removing invalidateOptionsMenu() and adding super.onDrawerOpened instead and super.onDrawerClosed.

Answer (score 0):

it has happened to me the solution was to init search menu item after invalidateOptionsMenu() even though it is already inited

```
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
```

and than:

```
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
```